# Web.config transform removes elements when building with VSTS

Tags: azure-pipelines, web.config-transform

We are using VSTS for continuous integration (CI). We configured an automatic build upon check-in, and then an automatic release when the build succeeds.
We added a build configuration called "CI" to the project, along with a web.CI.config transform file to replace app settings and connection strings to match the target environment, and a "CI" publish profile, using the CI configuration.

When the build is done by VSTS, the resulting web.config file has a lot of elements missing. Specifically, the <system.web> section is almost empty; elements such as <authentication>, <pages> or <siteMap> are missing, which result in the web site not working.

System.web section from the resulting web.config file:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
</system.web>
```

The transformations on the <appSettings> and <connectionStrings> sections are applied correctly. Also, when I publish locally (from Visual Studio Enterprise 2015) using the CI profile, the config transform is done as expected (no elements missing from system.web, site running as expected).

I assume that the VSTS build applies other transformations additionally to those specified in web.CI.config.

The question is: how do I prevent VSTS build from transforming the web.config file?

### VSTS Configuration

Here is how the build step is configured in VSTS:

- **Solution**: **\*.sln
- **MSBuild Arguments**: /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=CI /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True
- **Platform**: $(BuildPlatform)
- **Configuration**: $(BuildConfiguration)
- **Clean**: *(not checked)*
- **Visual Studio Version**: Visual Studio 2015

The variables are configured in the Variables section:

- **BuildConfiguration**: CI
- **BuildPlatform**: any cpu

The Advanced and Control Options sections were left with the default values.

The build step type is **Visual Studio Build**. I have also tried **MSBuild** with the same result.

### Web.config file

(sensitive information removed)

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="AspNetPerformance.Tools">
      <section name="Caching" requirePermission="false" type="AspNetPerformance.Tools.Configuration.AspNetPerformanceSection, AspNetPerformance.Tools"/>
      <section name="Minifying" requirePermission="false" type="AspNetPerformance.Tools.Configuration.AspNetPerformanceSection, AspNetPerformance.Tools"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="TheKey" value="TheValue" />
    <!-- other add elements -->
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>    
    <add name="FirstConnectionString" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="SecondConnectionString" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />      
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <trace enabled="true"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <pages enableSessionState="true" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="Static">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="atk" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
        <!-- other add elements -->
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <siteMap enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomXmlSiteMapProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="CustomXmlSiteMapProvider" type="..." securityTrimmingEnabled="false" siteMapFile="Web.sitemap"/>
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true"/>
    <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <globalization uiCulture="en-US" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

### Web.CI.config file

(sensitive information removed)

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="TheKey" value="TheNewValue" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
    <!-- all other settings transformed the same way -->
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FirstConnectionString" connectionString="NewValue" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    <add name="SecondConnectionString" connectionString="NewValue" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I posted the Web.config and Web.CI.config because it was asked, but I repeat that the expected transforms are performed (including the removal of the debug attribute in the compilation element under system.web). Also, the resulting Web.config file is as expected when I deploy locally using the CI configuration. I don't think the problem is in the web.config transform itself but in VSTS.

Comment: Is the value of BuildPlatform and BuildConfiguration configured in the Variables section?

Comment: What's the detail code of web.CI.config?

Comment: Also, What's the detail code of web.config?

Comment: I added the details of the Variables and config files.

Comment: There isn't httpRuntime section in web.config and Web.CI.config, but it is in the result web.config file. How do you get the result web.config file? What're detail steps of your build definition? Can you share the detail build log on the OneDrive?